# Is it possible to have different internal and public DNS with DNSSEC?

Tags: domain-name-system, dnssec, split-dns

I'm attempting to achieve the following:

- A public nameserver for my domain which points `example.com` to a public IP address.
- A private nameserver for the same domain running within a LAN which instead points clients to a private IP address on the same LAN.
- DNSSEC enabled.

Achieving the first and last points together is of course comparatively easy so it's getting the private component to work that's the issue.

In terms of my actual setup:

- I'm using Cloudflare's DNS service, where I have an A record for my domain pointing to a public IP address and DNSSEC enabled.
- At my registrar, I've added a DS record based on what Cloudflare gives me and configured Cloudflare's nameservers. All of this works fine, as you'd expect.
- Internally I'm running Pi-Hole (set as the DNS server for clients on my LAN) which is configured with DNSSEC enabled and pointing to a local CoreDNS instance as the upstream resolver.
- In CoreDNS, I have a zone configured for `example.com` which is signed with keys generated by `coredns-keygen`. This has an A record pointing to an internal IP address.
- I have a second DS record at my registrar based on the key used internally by CoreDNS.

What happens:

- The general setup works for resolving domains which aren't mine.
- Pi-Hole responds with `SERVFAIL` and logs `ABANDONED` when I attempt to resolve my domain.
- But, if I point a client directly to CoreDNS (e.g. with `dig`), I get the response expected with the LAN IP address.
- Also, if I disable DNSSEC in Pi-Hole, it works fine.

So my questions are:

- Is what I'm trying to achieve even possible?
- I'm starting to wonder if having separate DS records at my registrar is wrong, but I don't think I can retrieve the private key Cloudflare is using and nor can I upload custom keys, so I'm not sure how I can use the same keys for public and private.
- Is there any reason why things seem to work if I point my clients to CoreDNS directly but Pi-Hole is refusing to cooperate?

Thanks!

Comment: The following question in the Related column may help: https://serverfault.com/questions/745270/using-dnssec-with-private-tld?rq=1

Comment: "I'm starting to wonder if having separate DS records at my registrar is wrong" DNSSEC expects ONE valid path existing to prove chain of trust. Not all. So it is "fine" having extra DS. You can find various TLDs/domains using a "pre-published DS" setup where the DS is published at parent, without the relevant DNSKEY published at child. It works as long as there is ANOTHER DS record with its proper DNSKEY in place. You might want ,from the Pi-Hole to debug further the SERVFAIL. It can be DNSSEC related, or not. If you have EDE it helps, but otherwise try dig with and without `+cd`

Comment: A real name would have helped. I guess the problem is more related to your `NS` records.  "In CoreDNS, I have a zone configured for example.com which is signed with keys generated by coredns-keygen." But with probably different NS records than the public version of the zone? Which can induces errors on the signatures as the NS rrset will not match anymore.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen that question, but unfortunately the links in the answer are dead. Also, I do own my real domain so that presumably makes it easier. So having multiple DS records is fine? But when you say DNSSEC expects one path, presumably that means not ONLY one path. If I try dig with `+cd`, I get `NOERROR`, so this issue is definitely related to the checking. "But with probably different NS records than the public version of the zone?" - Ah, yes. I've just tried setting the SOA and NS of the internal zone to the same as the public, no change so far.

Comment: Also going to try and get something more helpful errors from the Pi-Hole. Going to look into if I can get EDE enabled somehow.

Comment: "But when you say DNSSEC expects one path, presumably that means not ONLY one path." The resolver takes all the DS it sees, and all the DNSKEY it sees, and if it finds one match (plus all the crypto and dates stuff becoming ok) then it is good to assert the chain of trust is verified (and it goes on with the next level of delegation, and so on). Once a valid path is found, other DS/DNSKEY at the same level are irrelevant, even if they work too.

Comment: See §5.3.3 of RFC4035 if it is clearer than my explanation: "Note that it is possible for more than one DNSKEY RR to match the
   conditions in Section 5.3.1.  In this case, the validator can only
   determine which DNSKEY RR is correct by trying each matching public
   key until the validator either succeeds in validating the signature
   or runs out of keys to try." So one match is enough to matter which one (in presence of multiple DNSKEY/DS; remember also that a given DNSKEY even alone can have multiple DS records, for different digests)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'm still stuck on this unfortunately. All I can see from the logs is that the Pi-Hole forwards the query to CoreDNS, which responds with the A record. The Pi-hole then queries for the DS record, CoreDNS logs a `NOERROR` response, but the Pi-Hole then logs `validation mydomain.com is ABANDONED`. Trying things with `dig` and `drill` querying the CoreDNS server directly, all I can say is that to the best of my understanding the responses look correct. So I have no idea why Pi-Hole is abandoning the validation.